# Get seed of Java's RNG with getInt(int n) method

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I am pretty interested in how Java RNG works. I've read that it's pretty easy using the `getLong()` method, and with `getInt()` and two values. I am interested in getting the seed with `getInt(int n)` knowing the value of `n`.

Since `getInt(n)` normally uses 
`val = bits % n;` and repeat it until `bits - val + (n-1) >= 0)`, being bits `next(31)` so val == bits (mod n)

I've tested a bruteforce testing all posible pair of numbers which are congruent with the initial one, but this is very long and difficult for a computer.

Any other ideas on how to get the seed on a efficient way?

Comment: Where did you read it's easy with `getLong`? Also, do you mean with the first call to `getInt` or an arbitrary call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236151/inverse-function-of-javas-random-function
And calling getInt() without parameters 2 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Reflection for this:

```
Random r = new Random(1);

Field f;
try {
    f = r.getClass().getDeclaredField("seed");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    AtomicLong seed = (AtomicLong) f.get(r);
    System.out.println("seed: " + seed);

    f = r.getClass().getDeclaredField("mask");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Long mask = (Long) f.get(r);
    System.out.println("mask: " + mask);

    f = r.getClass().getDeclaredField("multiplier");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Long multiplier = (Long) f.get(r);
    System.out.println("multiplier: " + multiplier);


    long initialSeed = (seed.longValue() ^ multiplier);
    System.out.println("restored initial seed: " + initialSeed);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
} catch (SecurityException e2) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e3) {
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e4) {
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
seed: 25214903916
mask: 281474976710655
multiplier: 25214903917
restored initial seed: 1
```

When the `seed` is set, the value is scrambled:

```
public Random(long seed) {
    if (getClass() == Random.class)
        this.seed = new AtomicLong(initialScramble(seed));
    else {
        // subclass might have overriden setSeed
        this.seed = new AtomicLong();
        setSeed(seed);
    }
}

private static long initialScramble(long seed) {
    return (seed ^ multiplier) & mask; // (seed XOR multiplier) AND mask
}
```

However, the `mask` and `multiplier` are just defined as:

```
private static final long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
```

As the `mask` is all `1`s for the least significant 48 bits and the XOR is reversible, you can get back the initial seed if (and only if!) it was smaller than (1L << 48), i.e. 2^48:

The output for:

```
Random r = new Random((1L << 48)-1);

seed: 281449761806738
mask: 281474976710655
multiplier: 25214903917
restored initial seed: 281474976710655
```

and for:

```
Random r = new Random((1L << 48));

seed: 25214903917
mask: 281474976710655
multiplier: 25214903917
restored initial seed: 0
```

See also [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

Comment: Is it not possible to deduct the original seed when you have the resulting seed and the operations performed?

Comment: Let me check, I think it is possible if the initial seed is smaller than 2^48

Comment: See my updated answer on how to get the initial seed value back.

Comment: Added the output for the corner cases `(1L << 48)-1` and `(1L << 48)`.

Comment: Very nicely answered!